# PHP 5 code, Can I upgrade mysql from mysql 5.5?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, compatibility, php-5.5

I am working with a old ~2013 Drupal site with a lot of custom php 5 code woth a bunch of extra mysql database tables. The mysql version is 5.5. I need to setup a new mysql server. I would like to use a hosted mysql V8 from Digital Ocean. Should this be backward compatible?

I have no experience with php and would not know what to look for with regard to compatibility.

- Drupal version 7.
- PHP 5.5
- Mysql 5.5

Comment: _"Should this be backward compatible"_ A change in major version will never be backward compatible. That said, it's unlikely you're using any features that were deprecated. Check the MySQL upgrade docs for v6, v7, and v8 to learn about what was deprecated.

Comment: MariaDB probably has a greater compatibility with MySQL-5.5 than MySQL-8.0 according [to their common founder](https://monty-says.blogspot.com/2020/04/upgrading-between-major-mariadb-versions.html). Failing that you can get mysql:5.5 and php:5.5 containers for the bundled obsolescence feeling :-).

Comment: @Alex Howansky, mr. MySQL Expert, there are no MySQL upgrade docs for v6 or v7.

Comment: There's  no such mysql versions as 6 or 7 because they skipped the numbers, but apart from that the advice you got is quite sensible and would apply to upgrading any software component

Comment: Thank you Everyone, I will got it a try.
Are there any tools to search the PHP code for possible mysql incompatibility?

Comment: No, other than your own eyes. Anyway it's not the php which would be an issue, it's any SQL code within it